# Informação Duplicando no SDCARD

Tags: arduino

Olá

Eu estou estudando o uso da SDCARD no Arduino e eu preciso gravar os valores dos sensores em um arquivo .TXT, mas ele fica duplicando as informações no arquivo .TXT enquanto passa pelo laço FOR, por que será ? Estou rachando a cuca a noite inteira, mas não estou achando o erro, pode ser algo muito bobo, mas não estou localizando. Oque esta errado ?

Esta gravando assim:

```
Um
Dois
Um
Dois
```

Meu código:

```
 #include <SdFat.h>

 SdFat sdCard;
 SdFile meuArquivo;

 const int chipSelect = 4;

 void setup()
 {
 // nada a ser feito no setup
 Serial.begin(9600);

 // Inicializa o modulo SD
 if(!sdCard.begin(chipSelect,SPI_HALF_SPEED))sdCard.initErrorHalt();
 // Abre o arquivo TESTANDO.TXT
 if (!meuArquivo.open("testando.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_AT_END))
 {
   sdCard.errorHalt("Erro na abertura do arquivo testando.txt!");
 } 

}

void loop()
{
   gravar();
 }

 void gravar()
 {
  for (int i=0; i <= 20; i++){

  Serial.println(i);
  delay(10);

  if(i == 1)
  {
    Serial.println("Um");
    meuArquivo.println("Um");
  }
  else if(i == 2)
  {
    Serial.println("dois");
    meuArquivo.println("Dois");
    meuArquivo.close();
    while(1){};
  }
   else
  {

  }
   delay(100);
 } 
}
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `loop()` é executada infinitamente e na função `gravar()` você cria uma variável `i` e atribui um valor `0` todas as vezes que a função `gravar()` é chamada (infinitamente). Experimente fazer assim:

```
#include <SdFat.h>

 SdFat sdCard;
 SdFile meuArquivo;

 const int chipSelect = 4;
 int executaUmaVez = 0;
 void setup()
 {
 // nada a ser feito no setup
 Serial.begin(9600);

 // Inicializa o modulo SD
 if(!sdCard.begin(chipSelect,SPI_HALF_SPEED))sdCard.initErrorHalt();
 // Abre o arquivo TESTANDO.TXT
 if (!meuArquivo.open("testando.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_AT_END))
 {
   sdCard.errorHalt("Erro na abertura do arquivo testando.txt!");
 } 

}

void loop()
{
    if(executaUmaVez ==0){
       gravar();
       executaUmaVez=1;
    }
 }

 void gravar()
 {
  for (int i=0; i <= 20; i++){

  Serial.println(i);
  delay(10);

  if(i == 1)
  {
    Serial.println("Um");
        meuArquivo.println("Um");
  }
  if(i == 2)
  {
    Serial.println("dois");
    meuArquivo.println("Dois");
    meuArquivo.close();
   }
   delay(100);

 } 
}
```

Comment: Eu testei e continua duplicando as informações gravadas no cartão de memória, estranho isso, não tem lógica, esta aparecendo assim ( Um, Dois, Um, Dois )

Comment: @abduzeedo Fiz uma pequena alteração no código. Tente experimentar agora.

Comment: Agora deu certo. Oque estava errado ?

Comment: No `else if(i===2)` há um while, eu apenas removi aquele while :)

Comment: Obrigado! :D :D

Comment: Avelino, muito estranho, eu copiei o seu codigo e colei e funcionou, mas depois de usar algumas vezes, ele comçe a duplicar novamente, porque será ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39095/discussion-between-abduzeedo-and-avelino).